# Can't express a certain query on my database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database for a chat application: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9e068/1

Let's take all the Users that have received at least one message from User "John". I want to define the number of all other users that have sent a message (one or more) to ALL the users that have received at least one message from User "John"

I consider that the key to the solution of this query is the double negation. The expression: "User U that has sent a message to ALL the recipients of User's John messages" is equal to the expression "No recipient from User "John" that User U hasn't sent a message to"

I have written a code about my approach but it's not correct:

```
SELECT U.name
FROM Users as U
WHERE  NOT EXISTS

(SELECT M.recipient
FROM Messages as M
WHERE M.sender = U.uid)

EXCEPT 

(SELECT mm.recipient
FROM Users as uu ,Messages as mm
WHERE uu.uid = mm.sender and uu.name = 'John')
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have put a link with the database. I practise online. How can I tag the question with it?

Comment: Based on your fiddle, I have tagged PostgreSQL. If you're not really using PostgreSQL, then retag to the right database. In the future, please make sure to tag correctly yourself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ok got it!Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Also, add the expected results and actual results in your question, and make sure to clearly describe the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What double negation?  That seems so complicated.

One method is to compare counts -- but they have to be the right counts:

```
select u.uid, count(*), count(distinct m.recipient)
from messages mj join
     users uj
     on mj.sender = uj.uid join
     users u
     on u.uid <> uj.uid left join  -- all combinations of john's recipients and other users
     messages m
     on m.recipient = mj.recipient and
        m.sender = u.uid
where uj.name = 'John'
group by u.uid
having count(distinct m.recipient) = count(distinct mj.recipient);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer in order to return the number of senders (without including John himself in the result) so that I accept it

Comment: This works great but it doesn't return the number of senders . It returns their names. How do I get the number of them? (Just a single number as a result). Fix this and I accept the answer since it solves the problem.

Comment: @MJ13 . . . You can use this as a subquery and use `count(*)`.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff : Just tested the query and doesn't seem to work. Check: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cbb03/3 . The result is wrong!

Comment: @MJ13 . . . It is a subtle error, but it should be fixed now.